# Remove Latex Markup Over Multiple Lines

Tags: perl, sed, latex

I have a LaTex document which is filled with markup that I want to remove. Suppose the document looks like this.

```
Here is some text, we can have inline $math$ symbols and \emph{markup}. 
Sometimes we find offset equations,

\[
  p(\theta|y) \propto p(y|\theta)p(\theta)
\]

And then we return to some more text.
```

I want to remove all the markup and I don't  need to keep the text which is wrapped in markup.

So for the `$...$` and `\emph{...}` kinds of things, something like `sed -E 's/\$[a-z]+\$//'` will work fine.

My question is how can I remove the equations that extend across multiple lines. I'd want to remove everything between `\[` and `\]` inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Range Operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to remove text between two patterns across multiple lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*\\\[/ .. /^\s*\\\]/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Here is some text, we can have inline $math$ symbols and \emph{markup}. 
Sometimes we find offset equations,

\[
  p(\theta|y) \propto p(y|\theta)p(\theta)
\]

And then we return to some more text.
```

Outputs:

```
Here is some text, we can have inline $math$ symbols and \emph{markup}. 
Sometimes we find offset equations,


And then we return to some more text.
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'next if /^\s*\\\[/ .. /^\s*\\\]/; print' file.tex
```

Switches:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.